# equation environment and large fractions

Tags: equations, amsmath, fractions

Hello i am currently using the equation environment and trying to "prettily" write down the probability distribution function of the chi-distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution)
This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\cfoot[]{}
\author{James Oliver Reppin}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

My code snippet currently looks like this:

```
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.} 
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\chapter{asd}
\section{asd1}
\subsection{Chi-distribution}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
&f(x) = \dfrac{x^{k-1}e^{-\dfrac{x^{2}}{2}}}{2^{\dfrac{k}{2}} \Gamma\left(\dfrac{k}{2}\right)},\;\;x\in \left[0,\infty\right),\;\;k>0\\
&blabla
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

My problem is, the huge fraction with exponents and such is weirdly proportioned, especially the denominator, where the exponents are displayed bigger than the actual base. Is there a way to make it prettier, aka have it look more like on the wikipedia page?

Comment: Please make your example into a simple piece of code that others can just copy and test as is. Sniplets like this are not particularly useful

Comment: i edited the question, i think with the preamble and the snipped one should be able to recreate my problem, since i just left out the bibliography, titlepage and the table of content

Comment: you are over-riding the normal styling and forcing display style fractions in a superscript which will look weird.  also don't use aligned for single line equations

Comment: i am using aligned because there will be more equations which i left out for this question since they are not important. With forcing display style, you mean \dfrac ?

Comment: you have posted two fragments but neither allows anyone to simply run the example.  can you replace themby a single small but complete example

Comment: yes there are rather few case where dfrac should be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the slashed form for fractions in exponents; surely not `\dfrac`.

```latex
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&f(x) =
  \dfrac{x^{k-1}e^{-x^2/2}}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)},
  \qquad x\in [0,\infty),\quad k>0\\
&blabla
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

The version with `\frac` is much less readable, in my opinion.

```latex
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&f(x) =
  \dfrac{x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{2^{\frac{k}{2}}\Gamma\Bigl(\dfrac{k}{2}\Bigr)},
  \qquad x\in [0,\infty),\quad k>0\\
&blabla
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: i like your first method using the slashed form the most, so i upvoted your answer as the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to *not* use `\dfrac` in exponents. I replaced this command with `\tfrac` (in the exponents) and with `\mfrac` (medium-sized fraction, from `nccmath`) for the argument of the Γ function. For a better spacing I also replaced a pair `\left(...\right)` with the pair `\Bigl(...\Bigr)` and improved the layout of the `-\tfrac{x^2}{2}` exponent:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\cfoot[]{}
\author{James Oliver Reppin}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{asd}
\section{asd1}
\subsection{Chi-distribution}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
&f(x) = \dfrac{x^{k-1}e^{-\tfrac{\,x^{\mathrlap{2}}}{2}}}{2^{\tfrac{k}{2}}\, \Gamma\Bigl(\mfrac{k}{2}\Bigr)},\;\;x\in \left[0,\infty\right),\;\;k>0\\
&blabla
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]